How can I install Laravel Nova::SearchableRelation?
Going through Laravel Nova documentation, I noticed that SearchableRelation appears to be a built-in feature in Nova. However, I couldn't find it in my project.
How can I install or enable it?
For reference: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/v5/search/the-basics#searching-relationships
I also created a new Nova project to test, but SearchableRelation was still not available.

Can you confirm you are on Laravel Nova 5, and not an earlier release

@JonMenard I am at an earlier release, v.3.32.0. Linked the documentation for v5 as I couldn't find any docs for v3.
